# Trying to extract a specific tag/attribute from huge xml document

Tags: xml, xmllint

I am trying to extract some specific data from a huge (>1.5 million lines) xml document using xmllint on a Linux system and not having much luck with the xmllint syntax. I have been doing this very inefficiently using grep and awk but I found out this system has the xmllint utility (which I've never used) and I figured since xml is well structured, there ought to be a way to access the data directly. I have included a snippet of the xml document, however in paring it down I have caused xmllint to have parser errors though it looks correct to me. I figure if you are xmllint savvy enough to answer my question, you can probably easily figure out the parser error.

Based on web searches I have tried this syntax:

````
cat //*/@index' | xmllint --shell stub.xml (which does return ALL of the "indexes")
and
test=$(xmllint --debug --xpath "//PTC/BPSETS/BPSET/BPS" stub.xml) (which does dump the entire BPS entry)
and
xmllint --xpath "string(//PTC/BPSETS/BPSET/@b95)" stub.xml (returns no values)

Here is the xml snippet as best as I can trim it down:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PTC version="2.0" cls="2">
  <BPSETS>
    <BPSET define="b95">
      <BPS define="88lmax">
        <CRIT>
          <MNBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBT red="Y" />
        </CRIT>
        <PNS>
          <PN index="0" atv="1" bf="32203506">
            <AWD cpbt="390">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="1" atv="1" bf="24237243">
            <AWD cpbt="390">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="2" atv="1" bf="8136575">
            <AWD cpbt="390">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
        </AWD>
      </PN>
          <PN index="688" atv="1" bf="1183872">
            <AWD cpbt="50" />
          </PN>
        </PNS>
      </BPS>
      <BPS define="88l6">
        <CRIT>
          <MNBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBT lmt="6" />
          <MNBT lmt="6" />
        </CRIT>
        <PNS>
          <PN index="0" atv="1" bf="28073582">
            <AWD cpbt="150">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="1" atv="1" bf="16686973">
            <AWD cpbt="150">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
    </PNS>

      </BPS>
      <BPS define="88l4">
        <CRIT>
          <MNBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBT lmt="4" />
          <MNBT lmt="4" />
        </CRIT>
        <PNS>
          <PN index="0" atv="1" bf="31342257">
            <AWD cpbt="50">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="1" atv="1" bf="13761775">
            <AWD cpbt="50">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
        </PNS>
      </BPS>
      <BPS define="88l2">
        <CRIT>
          <MNBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBT lmt="2" />
          <MNBT lmt="2" />
        </CRIT>
        <PNS>
          <PN index="0" atv="1" bf="16291759">
            <AWD cpbt="10">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="1" atv="1" bf="15032283">
            <AWD cpbt="10">
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
        </PNS>
      </BPS>
      <BPS define="88l1">
        <CRIT>
          <MNBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBS lmt="88" />
          <MXBT lmt="1" />
          <MNBT lmt="1" />
        </CRIT>
        <PNS>
          <PN index="0" atv="1" bf="33278739">
            <AWD>
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="1" atv="1" bf="7261567">
            <AWD>
              <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
              <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
            </AWD>
          </PN>
          <PN index="896" atv="1" bf="101540">
            <AWD cpbt="10" />
          </PN>
          <PN index="897" atv="1" bf="3680792">
            <AWD cpbt="10" />
          </PN>
          <PN index="898" atv="1" bf="25776896">
            <AWD cpbt="10" />
          </PN>
        </PNS>
      </BPS>
    </BPSET>

    <BPSET define="b94" use="b95">
      <BPS define="88mx">
        <PNS>
          <PN index="422" atv="1" bf="11692089">
            <AWD cpbt="9000" />
          </PN>
          <PN index="424" atv="1" bf="12200338">
            <AWD cpbt="7200" />
          </PN>
          <PN index="427" atv="1" bf="24210225">
            <AWD cpbt="6000" />
          </PN>
       </PNS>
      <BPS>
    </BPSET>

  </BPSETS>
</PTC>





What I really need is a query that returns all the attribute's contained in a specific element  under a specific index e.g.:


<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <PTC version="2.0" cls="2">
      <PN index="0" atv="1" bf="32203506">
        <AWD cpbt="390">
          <BUNS ptgp="bn38" bdx="38" fawd="1" />
          <BUNS ptgp="bn39" bdx="39" fawd="1" awby="38" />
        </AWD>
      </PN>


A query that given a PN index value (e.g. 0) would return the values of bf and cbpt…

If it were an sql query the xmllint query I'm looking for would be something like:
```sql
select bf,cbpt from PTC.BPSETS.BPSET.BPS.PNS.PN 
where BPSET = "b95" AND BPS = 88lmax AND PN.index = 0.
````

If you follow my drift.
Any guidance here appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete XML file you have. If possible prove a [mcve], the commands you are trying to run and the error messages you get. Check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for any formatting help. And don't "scream", you are not helping anyone by this.

Comment: xml snippet added back into the body where I suspect it is not checked for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Further research and experimentation indicates this is the syntax required:

echo 'cat //PTC/BPSETS/BPSET[@define="b95"]/BPS[@define="88lmax"]/PNS/PN[@index="0"]/AWD/@cpbt' | xmllint --shell stub.xml

This yields the desired data.